# How to transfer something(i.e variable) from a JavaScript file to a HTML file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a web-page that will display a pie-chart with results but the code for my pie-chart is in a HTML file (read_data.html) and the figures I would like to use for the pie-chart are in a JavaScript file (read_data.js)

The figures I want are stored in 4 variables - **Booth1,Booth2,Booth3,Booth4**

How could I go about transferring these variables to my HTML file?

**Here is the code for the pie-chart in the HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Students', 'Votes'],
  ['Canidate1', Booth1],
  ['Canidate2', Booth2],
  ['Canidate3', Booth3],
  ['Canidate4', Booth4],
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Election Results', 'width':550, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the code in the JavaScript file**

```
// Lists to hold the well being states and their corresponding times
var myVotes = [];
var myTimes = [];

// Variables to hold the count for each state
var Booth1 = 0;
var Booth2 = 0;
var Booth3 = 0;
var Booth4 = 0;

// Define database connection to correct child branch, ElectionResults
var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("ElectionResults");

// Function that acts when a 'new child is added to the DB' - i.e. new data is added this function runs.
myDBConn.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
  Booth1 = 0;
  Booth2 = 0;
  Booth3 = 0;
  Booth4 = 0;

  // The data returned from the branch is put into a variable, dataPoint
  var dataPoint = data.val();

  // Populate the lists with the various data from the database
  myVotes.push(dataPoint.ElectionResults);
  myTimes.push(dataPoint.Time);

  // Loop each returned state and add 1 to the appropriate counter
  for (i = 0; i < myVotes.length; i++) {
    if (myVotes[i] == "Canidate1") {
      Booth1 = Booth1 + 1;
    }
    if (myVotes[i] == "Canidate2") {
      Booth2 = Booth2 + 1;
    }
    if (myVotes[i] == "Canidate3") {
      Booth3 = Booth3 + 1;
    }
    if (myVotes[i] == "Canidate4") {
      Booth4 = Booth4 + 1;
    }
  }

  // Update the page elements with the average and the last item (most rescent) off the list
  document.getElementById("TimeID").innerHTML = myTimes[myTimes.length - 1];

  // Update the page elements with the results of each count
  document.getElementById("Booth1").innerHTML = Booth1;
  document.getElementById("Booth2").innerHTML = Booth2;
  document.getElementById("Booth3").innerHTML = Booth3;
  document.getElementById("Booth4").innerHTML = Booth4;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just include the JS file into the HTML file by useing the `<script />` tag;

```
<script type="something" src="read_data.js"></script>
```

With this tag you inculded the file and can use the variables by opening another `script` tag;

```
<script>
  //import variables here
</script>
```